# converting xml data type in sql server to mongodb

Tags: c#, sql-server, json, xml, mongodb

Just wondering if there's a way to facilitate a procedure, where I have an xml document, no attributes, it's purely nodal, that is saved within a column of a table in sql server, then traverse through this column, and convert it to json, then take that final outcome, and dump it into mongodb?

It does seem like a tall order, but I feel like there must be a way where I can take each xml data object stored in this column, convert to json in c# using some library (I seen some out there that exists), but I really don't want the hassle of dumping them into a file. The process of the conversion and dumping into mongodb seems like it'd take a very very long time to parse and insert. So I was wondering if there's an alternative route that'd make my long journey less troublesome.

[EDIT: adding example] 
Here's an example of what could be in a column as xml data in a sql server column:

```
<Person>
    <FirstName><![CDATA[John]]></FirstName>
    <LastName><![CDATA[Doe]]></LastName>
<Person>
```

Or sometimes, I could have a list of things:

```
<Cities>
    <City>
         <Name>Cleveland</Name>
         <State>Ohio</Name>
    </City>
    <City>
         <Name>San Francisco</Name>
         <State>California</State>
    </City>
</Cities>
```

Now, is there a way to take these examples, convert them to json, in a bulk way for each column containing xml, and then dump them into mongodb? Do I have to write out this process in c#? What's a good way of completing this task efficiently?

Comment: It's a bit broad an ask here, especially without sample data and a desired output. It's not hard though, just a matter of parsing the XML and submitting into a format acceptable for your BSON object. This is still all subjective as to how the XML is actually formatted ( ie with attributes on the element ) and how the parser you are using deals with this. It may well be that you need to do some custom manipulation. But from your current question format, no-one can tell.

Comment: All my xml documents,  as I stated.. Has no attributes.. They are all nodes.. Why should I put an example of an xml document if the description of the xml document is exactly as implied? I know it's not hard, I just want to know of a useful approach. I don't mean to sound condescending, but I don't really want to see a response saying I'm too broad because there isn't an example. The whole question is direct as I can possibly make it.

Comment: You're more likely to get responses on stackoverflow if you break the question down into more atomic parts.  For the XML to JSON conversion, consider Json.NET: [Converting between JSON and XML](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConvertingJSONandXML.htm).

Comment: Json.NET can also [serialize to BSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeToBson.htm), though I don't know how compatible it is with MongoDB.

Comment: @dbc, I'm interested to know that question too. I have like 15 columns, all having xml data, with like 8000 records, and we keep on adding more rows to it, I want to remove all of those and have mongodb store that data.

Comment: Btw..the reason why I would handle JSON, and not BSON.. is because of the extra support provided within C#. And because of mongodb's ability of reading JSON into BSON. That's why I wasn't even factoring XML to BSON.. but if there's anything that supports that conversion in sql server, or c# or whatever, I'll gladly accept that! I've seen xml to json converters before.